# using Firebase as read only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to move my json file to an database service. I've been looking at Firebase-- Firestore in particular.

What the website is, is a collection of recipes. 
Users can search for recipes by category. Or they can search by typing in ingredient.

I dont need to have users signing up and logging in.

Its not overly clear to me:

1. If this service can be used as a 'read only' database to populate the website with what the user selects.
2. If the database can be secure yet not have users sign up and log in.

Can anyone direct me to documentation/tutorial on the "how to" to have the data itself secured, but available for read only and without needing users to create log-ins.

Thank you,
Lee

Comment: "is there something better, simpler to apply for this situation?" That sort of question is off topic on Stack Overflow, since it attracts opinionated answers and discussions. I recommend removing it and sticking to the "how can I do this" parts of your question.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I edited as per request.

Comment: It's a pretty broad question but there are a couple of answers. If your database is 'read only' then you are totally secure against someone writing bad data, and yes, Firebase can very easily be set to read-only. Keeping in mind that read only for all opens all your data up to read by anyone at any time. Firebase does not require users sign up - you can open it up to be read by anyone. See Firebase [Secure Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) for some reading on security.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jay. I'm just getting into backend server storage and trying to sort through what is needed for a simple site of displaying data for any user. No logins needed, no change of the data by the user to be done.
I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Yes

You need to look into [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to make sure your public read-only data is actually read only:  Just `allow read: if true` for each collection that you want to give access.

Comment: Thank you Doug.  For clarification, when the collections are set to `allow read`, will I need to set security elsewhere seeing I don't need nor want to have user ids and logins?

Comment: No, I gave you config that allows unconditional public read access.  If you want a document to be read only by authenticated user accounts, you have to write that into the config.  You should go through the linked docs to understand how things work.

Comment: Ok, was seeking clarification for what I was reading in the docs. Thank you for your time and patience on the matter.